# All java windows blank after installing Java 7 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 Server

Tags: java, osx-lion

I recently upgraded to JDK 7 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 Server.  All java windows for all the java programs running on my machine webstart or otherwise are now empty.  Even the Java Control Panel is a blank screen. I have tried uninstalling an re-installing the JDK but I have had no luck.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks
Todd

[image: Java Control Panel]

Answer (score 3):

Uninstalling and reinstalling the JRE did not fix the windowing issue

Here are the steps I used to resolve this issue with 10.7.5:

1. Uninstall the JRE7: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml
2. Restart
3. Install Java for OS X 2012-006
4. Restart
5. Install JRE7
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1637588.html
6. Restart

Comment: I also uninstalled all JDK's I had installed. Removed the JRE. Installed the new one. Restart (necessary apparently).

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problems with my 10.7.5 server The answer by djdarkbeat did not work for me and I have spent the last couple of months trying to find a work around (apart from upgrading to mountain lion)

Today I installed the latest version of Java for OS X 2013-003 alongside Java 7u17. The java control panel window still will not paint when it first opens, I have been able to minimise and maximise to get a single paint to occur at a time. Using this crazy method I have been able to check out settings and partially get some of my java apps working.

It's not a full solution (yet) but it may help someone get somewhere when they realise the other solutions don't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't have an actual need for 7, (but this was a real nuisance for managing FileMaker server via their java-based admin console,) I just rolled back to 6 with the instructions Apple posted here(after making sure I had Apple's patched version of 6 from software update, by checking `java -version` in a terminal window): http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559

Answer (score 0):

If you still are having this problem after following djdarkbeat's answer and you're running a headless mac mini, you probably are running into the bug mentioned at the [end of this apple support thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4670680?start=15&tstart=0).

## Solutions

1. Connect a monitor to the DVI or HDMI-Port (with a Mini DisplayPort adapter to HDMI, DVI, VGA, etc...) <sup>[thanks to this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22190232#22190232)</sup>
2. Downgrade to Snow Leopard
3. [Build a dummy monitor dongle](https://macminicolo.net/blog/files/build-a-dummy-dongle-for-a-headless-mac-mini) to trick the Mac mini into loading video drivers.